What tags could we introduce to better distinguish topics concerned with different areas of mining?
We have over 1000 questions concerned with the topic of mining, yet the number of tags that further distinguish questions in that realm is pretty small:

mining, mining-pools, cgminer, miner, bfgminer, asicminer, pooled-mining, solo, diablominer, webminer, primeminer, mining-pool

A while back, there was a proposal for a "mining-related" stackexchange, which argued that our SE does not cater to that topic well enough.
Further related tags such as 
litecoin, gpu, asic, hashing, profitability, scrypt, and cpu essentially act as meta-tags for mining in those questions.
What do you think about introducing tags such as:

scrypt-mining
sha256d-mining
mining-performance
cpu-mining
asic-mining
mining-profitability

Would they be beneficial for users to properly distinguish mining related topics to follow?
What other terms are commonly used on Bitcoin related platforms to talk about questions on mining?
What tags should we introduce in order to better cater to the miners?

I'm open to suggestions, make it an answer! ;)
